Laravel illuminate/filesystem and laravel/framework coexist but did not find illuminate/filesystem in composer.json
I am updating laravel from composer but getting one error during updating it

Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/filesystem[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev, v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev, v11.0.0, ..., 11.x-dev], laravel/framework[v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/filesystem and thus cannot coexist with it

I check in composer.json file there is no  illuminate/filesystem in it.Can anybody tell me how to solve this issue?
I tried to create the composer.js file again but its not solve anything.

Can you share more details, like the content of your composer.json and the full and exact error message you're facing?

you could try

remove the vendor folder ( which deletes all the installed dependencies )
// run the cmd from your project root folder
rm -rf vendor


you could also delete the folder manually or using other tools/cmd
after deleting edit your composer.json by following official upgrade guide
try composer update  or freshly install the packages using
composer install


if you are upgrading from laravel 8, make sure you migrate properly according to the official laravel upgrade guide. This is strongly recommended if you are using ftp/sftp or amazon s3 (configs)


Write your composer.json.
illuminate/filesystem is included in laravel/framework.
No need to install it separately.
If you are using a third-party composer package, update that package.
